# Get IP of a specific host is not working over a network with Java

Tags: java, networking, ip-address

I'm not able to get IP of hostname over a network.
I can get public IP but seems not to work over a network because of missing protocol:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

    String url = "host22.my.network";
    getIp(url);
}

public static void getIp(String url) throws UnknownHostException{

    try { 
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(url).getHost()); 
        System.err.println(ip);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

maybe it's missing a protocol prefix

Comment: Maybe anything. What were the exception and its message? However your `String` constant is certainly *not* a URL. Hard to see why you are taking a perfectly good hostname, trying to convert it to a URL, only to then try to get the hostname back, when you already had it.

Comment: Message is "no protocol", what should I put as protocol ?

Comment: You don't need a protocol. You don't need a URL. You need a hostname, and you already have it.

Comment: @user207421 this is your opinion or did you also tried what you are saying ? Because the piece of code I've mentioned doesn't work with simple hostname

Comment: `InetAddtess.getByName()` takes a `String hostname` argument. This is not opinion but fact. Strange question. 'Doesn't work' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @ejp doesn't want to actually answer questions any more, here's what he's saying:

`new URL(url).getHost()` is wrong. Instead, use

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(url)
```

And since you're not actually passing a URL, rename the parameter to `hostname`.